# How to change class button when type textbox/input?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change the class of button when I type a number in the textbox.

I have a table, My table has many `tr`. And a tr have two textboxes and a button of submit.

Html

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <table class="table">
        <tbody>
        <tr class="bg-danger">
            <form action="">
                <td class="align-middle">
                    <p>
                        <input type="text" class="form-forecast showError" name="" id="" aria-label="" required>
                        <span class="errorMsg"></span>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <input type="text" class="form-forecast showError" name="" id="" aria-label="" required>
                        <span class="errorMsg"></span>
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td class="align-middle">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-secondary submit">Reg</button>
                </td>
            </form>
        </tr>
        <tr class="bg-warning">
            <form action="">
                <td class="align-middle">
                    <p>
                        <input type="text" class="form-forecast showError" name="" id="" aria-label="" required>
                        <span class="errorMsg"></span>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <input type="text" class="form-forecast showError" name="" id="" aria-label="" required>
                        <span class="errorMsg"></span>
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td class="align-middle">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-secondary submit">Reg</button>
                </td>
            </form>
        </tr>
        <tr class="bg-info">
            <form action="">
                <td class="align-middle">
                    <p>
                        <input type="text" class="form-forecast showError" name="" id="" aria-label="" required>
                        <span class="errorMsg"></span>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <input type="text" class="form-forecast showError" name="" id="" aria-label="" required>
                        <span class="errorMsg"></span>
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td class="align-middle">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-secondary submit">Reg</button>
                </td>
            </form>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
let vote_a = document.getElementById('vote_a');
let vote_b = document.getElementById('vote_b');
const allSubmitButton = document.querySelectorAll(".submit")

vote_a.addEventListener('input', event => {
    if (event.target.value !== '') {
        allSubmitButton.addClass('bg-warning').removeClass('bg-secondary');
    } else {
        allSubmitButton.addClass('bg-secondary').removeClass('bg-warning');
    }
});
```

Comment: where is that allSubmitButton? If you do not want to allow users to insert number they could be blocked completely.

Comment: Do you mean you don't know how to detect if the text is a number?

Comment: Yes, I don't know.

Comment: So the class will change if there is a number anywhere in the textbox, "abc7def"? or if the textbox only contains numbers "12345"?

Comment: If the textbox only contains the number "12345".

Comment: I wany to create site like this https://pishbini.varzesh3.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To detect if the value of your textbox is all numbers you can use this condition

```js
if(event.target.value.match(/^\d+$/))
{
  // change the class
}
```

It uses the regular expression `^\d+$` which checks if the text starts with, ends with and has numbers in the middle.

It works because `match` returns a falsey value if there is no match, which in this case means there is something as well as numbers in the text box.

Comment: It is not working

Comment: in what sense? is there an error message? have you tried any debugging yourself?

Comment: Yes, I see this error.  `Uncaught TypeError: allSubmitButton.addClass is not a function`

Comment: `allSubmitButton` is a list of buttons. you'll need to pick one.

Comment: Well, I want to select all the buttons.

Comment: you can iterate through the buttons with a loop, e.g. `for(let button of allSubmitButton){//change the class of a button}`